# WinPE, install multiple images

Tags: windows, winpe

I'm setting up a PXE environment with winPE, since we receive install.wim images with driver pre-injected, it will be easier to use those instead of installing them by hand.
Problem is, some users will want multiple OSs on one hard drive (ie: win7/8/10 in one HDD).
Is it possible to use winPE to install any number of windows installation in one go?

I was planning on creating a GUI using python (I checked and i can use portable python interpreter and a remote script to bring up the GUI), this GUI/script will handle all the partitions creation according to user selection, but if winPE can't install more then one installation it won't really help, I want the end product to be able to install any number of OSs according to user selection.

Answer (score 0):

WinPE is just a Windows executive able to run a "Setup.exe" process or apply a particular wim image. Forget about installing multiple OSs on a hard disk in just one go.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to just use .wim files on a .vhd and allow a Boot menu to let someone choose which .wim to boot into. They could all sit at the root level of the C:\drive and then make appropriate entries/permissions for each VHD.

It's a start, but an example is this site: http://www.howtogeek.com/75286/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-8-without-re-partitioning-using-vhd/

I haven't done it myself but I also know at one time you could use a raw .wim file as a boot device. BOOT-WIM as it were, but that is no deprecated as far as I know now that Win10 is out.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.